# Browser doesn't apply css are linked to svg which is source of img

Tags: html, css, svg

I have `svg`-file. it uses some `css`-file. If I open this `svg`-file in a browser then it looks fine.

If I set my `svg`-file like the source for the `img`-element of my `html`-file then I see that styles are not used. Can I fix it?

I know `svg` cannot to use the `css`-styles of `html`-document when it is placed on the `img`, but in my case this `css` is not belong to `html` and is linked to `svg` *directly*.

cat.svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="cat.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle cx='100' cy='100' r='50' class='cat-head'/>
    <g id='whisters'>
        <circle cx='125' cy='85' r='5' class='cat-eyes'/>
        <line x1='100' y1='100' x2='175' y2='85' class='cat-whiskers'/>
        <line x1='100' y1='100' x2='175' y2='115' class='cat-whiskers'/>
        <polyline points='125 110, 120 120, 100 120' class='cat-mouth'/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href='#whisters' transform='scale(-1 1) translate(-200 0)'/>
</svg>
```

cat.css file:

```
.cat-head{
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    fill: #ffcc66;
}

.cat-mouth{
    /*stroke: black;*/
    fill: none;
}

.cat-eyes{
    /*stroke: black;*/
    fill: green;
}

.cat-whiskers{
    /*stroke: black;*/
}

#whisters{
    stroke: black;
}
```

result:

[image]

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='cat.svg'/>
</body>
</html>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, you are not right, my question (and the answer) is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object` element solved my problem:

```
<object type='image/svg+xml' data='cat.svg'></object>
```